# client doesnt receive emitted value when server is stuck in while loop

Tags: react-native, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using flask SocketIO here is my starter file in the server:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = APP_SECRET_KEY
JWTManager(app)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.config['transports'] = 'websocket'
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
socketio.run(app, host=SERVER_IP, debug=True)
```

I have a simple route that emits to the client a message that it's purpose is to trigger the client to send the server a code that will allow the server to exit the while loop and continue the execution of the route. The route is as following:

```
@app.route('/socket')
    def send_socket():
        socketio.emit('custom', {'data': 123})
        code = ''
        while not code :pass
        // another logic here - after code received
```

In the client I subscribe to that event :

```
socket.on('custom', (data) => {
     // emit the code to the server
    });
```

I also have a button that triggers the api request to the server /socket route :

```
const response = await axios
      .get('http://serverip:5000/socket')
      .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
```

Figured out that the while loop is preventing the client from receiving the message as the server is stuck in the while loop the client doesnt receive the 'custom' event. As long as I remove the while loop the client receives the message.
Can someone explain me why the loop is preventing the client receiving the emit? I am certain that the server did emit the event, as it reaches the callback as long as I remove the while, and the emit happened before the loop. Is it related to flask SocketIO eventlet is not dealing with threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your while loop blocks the whole server, as you are running under eventlet. You can try running a `sleep(0)` inside your loop to prevent the blocking:

```py
while not code:
    socketio.sleep(0)
```

Comment: What exactly does this sleep do? If I add this line am I able to send requests to other routes?

Comment: The sleep allows the asynchronous engine from eventlet to run in the background. And yes, I think that will allow your server to respond to other requests while inside the loop.